# Don't receive BroadcastReceiver using sinch example

Tags: android, instant-messaging, sinch

I tried using this example in my app in order to have instant messaging
https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/
I call broadcast receiver to listen for the broadcast from my service, but it never succeed or fails. My progress dialog keep spinning forever, and no toast is shown.

My service:

```
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {
...
private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("il.ac.app.my.Activity.ListUsersActivity");
...
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    APP_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.sinch_key);
    APP_SECRET = getResources().getString(R.string.sinch_secret);
    ENVIRONMENT = getResources().getString(R.string.sinch_hostname);

    //get the current user id from Parse
    String currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
        startSinchClient(currentUserId);
    }
    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
...
@Override
public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
    messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
}
```

My activity:

```
private void showSpinner() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //broadcast receiver to listen for the broadcast from MessageService
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (!success) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Messaging service failed to start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Messaging service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("il.ac.app.my.Activity.ListUsersActivity"));
}
```

Comment: Your intents action and your intent filter differ. If you put the same for both it might work.

Comment: I cant change IntentFilter because registerReceiver expects IntentFilter.

Comment: Indeed, when I wrote my comment you had a different action in the intent filter than in the intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LoginActivity, try to start ListUsersActivity before Sinch Service as follows:

```
 startActivity(intent);
 startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: I am not sure this was the reason, but i found out i started the service twice by mistake. now it works fine

Comment: When starting SinchService before ListUsersActivity, the broadcast intent is sent before that the broadcastReceiver is registered. Consequently, the intent is removed by the Garbage Collector then the BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive anything and the spinner is loading indefinitely. Anyway, the tutorial was updated today because many readers face the problem with the spinner!

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this example in my app in order to have instant messaging https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/ I call broadcast receiver to listen for the broadcast from my service, but it never succeed or fails. My progress dialog keep spinning forever, and no toast is shown.

My service:

```
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {
...
private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("il.ac.app.my.Activity.ListUsersActivity");
...
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    APP_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.sinch_key);
    APP_SECRET = getResources().getString(R.string.sinch_secret);
    ENVIRONMENT = getResources().getString(R.string.sinch_hostname);

    //get the current user id from Parse
    String currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
        startSinchClient(currentUserId);
    }
    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
...
@Override
public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
    messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
}
```